# Add timedelta to date column based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my sample data

```
        Date    tf  tf_int
0   2022-01-01  D   1
1   2022-01-02  W   3
2   2022-01-03  M   2
3   2022-01-04  Y   2
```

I want to make a new column based that will add the required timedelta to the Date column.

For eg, for my first row, I want to add 1 day to the date (2022-1-1) so the result would be 2022-1-2

Is there any vectorised way to achieve this ?
I don't using multiple `.loc[]` calls to accomplish this separately for days,weeks, months etc; But I would prefer the solution to be vectorised

My unsuccessful attempt with `.loc[]`

```
df.loc[df['tf'] =='D','publish_date'] = df['Date'].dt.date + dt.timedelta(days = df['tf_int'])
```

But this results in error because df['tf_int'] is a series and not an exact value

Edit:
For my use case, adding one month will add affect only the month component, and not do anything to the date

Comment: Month and Year are not fixed frequencies, thus it is impossible to add 1 month without having more details on the exact rule. For instance, what is 2022-02-28 + 1 Month? 2022-03-28? 2022-04-02? something else?

Comment: But can something be done for the lower timeframes ?

Comment: So vectorization is not a requirement?

Comment: I was hoping for a vectorised solution. I still am. If someone would post a vectorised solution, I would change that as my answer. For now, I'm making do with _an_ answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need exact year and months is necessary use list comprhension solution with [`offsets.DateOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html):

```
d = {'D':'days','W':'weeks', 'M':'months', 'Y':'years'}

df['publish_date'] = [z + pd.offsets.DateOffset(**{d[y]: x}) 
                     for x, y, z in zip(df['tf_int'], df['tf'], df['Date'].dt.normalize())]
print (df)
        Date tf  tf_int publish_date
0 2022-01-01  D       1   2022-01-02
1 2022-01-02  W       3   2022-01-23
2 2022-01-03  M       2   2022-03-03
3 2022-01-04  Y       2   2024-01-04
```

Comment: can you tell me how you pasted the df on the answer with correct formatting ?

Comment: @Charizard_knows_to_code - I use 4 spaces before.

Comment: @jezrael I loved your solution but list comprehension is not mandatory, you can use apply with lambda: df['new_date'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Date + pd.offsets.DateOffset(**{delta[x.tf]: x.tf_int}), axis=1)

Comment: @Ze'evBen-Tsvi - it is more slowier like `DataFrame.apply` with `axis=1`, it was reason for use it

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for that info, I was sure that using loops (even if it is a comprehension loop) is somehow slower.

Answer (score 0):

If you accept to have approximations for Month/Year, a vectorial solution could be something like:

```
mapper = {'D': 1, 'W': 7, 'M': 30, 'Y': 365}
df['Date2'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
                 .add(pd.to_timedelta(df['tf'].map(mapper).mul(df['tf_int']),
                                      unit='D'))
              )
```

output:

```
        Date tf  tf_int      Date2
0 2022-01-01  D       1 2022-01-02
1 2022-01-02  W       3 2022-01-23
2 2022-01-03  M       2 2022-03-04
3 2022-01-04  Y       2 2024-01-04
```